# List only local user accounts with a single command

Tags: command-line, 18.04, users, user-management

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I need to list all the user accounts on the computer but not all of the accounts, only the local users.
the command `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` gives:

```
root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
...
pulse
avahi
colord
hplip
geoclue
gnome-initial-setup
gdm
esnow
stuartsnow
samsnow
```

Does anyone know of a command that would output only the local users, for example:

```
root
esnow
stuartsnow
samsnow
```

Comment: What do you mean by "local users"? All of those are local users. What is the difference between the users you have selected and the others? Why would `root` not be included in any list of real users?

Comment: These users are user accounts that you can log into and that are used by real people, rather than just user accounts for the operating system. I'm not sure what the term for that is sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the list of users that can actually log into the machine, look for the users whose login shell (the last field in `/etc/passwd`) is not set to `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin`:

```
$ awk -F: '$NF!~/\/false$/ && $NF!~/\/nologin$/' /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
terdon:x:1000:1000::/home/terdon:/bin/bash
git:x:996:996:git daemon user:/:/bin/bash
bib:x:1001:1001::/home/bib:/bin/bash
bob:x:1002:1002::/home/bob:/bin/bash
```

And to get the user name only:

```
$ awk -F: '$NF!~/\/false$/ && $NF!~/\/nologin$/{print $1}' /etc/passwd
root
sync
terdon
git
bib
bob
```

If you want only "normal" users, those who were created using the standard approach and therefore will have a home directory under `/home`, use:

```
$ awk -F: '$6~/\/home/' /etc/passwd
syslog:x:101:104::/home/syslog:/bin/false
terdon:x:1000:1000::/home/terdon:/bin/bash
bib:x:1001:1001::/home/bib:/bin/bash
bob:x:1002:1002::/home/bob:/bin/bash
```

And, for the username only:

```
$ awk -F: '$6~/\/home/{print $1}' /etc/passwd
syslog
terdon
bib
bob
```

Finally, you can combine the two to get all users with a home in `/home` *and* a valid login shell:

```
$ awk -F: '$NF!~/\/false$/ && $NF!~/\/nologin$/ && $6~/\/home/{print $1}' /etc/passwd
terdon
bib
bob
```

---

On a sane Ubuntu system, all of the non-system users [should have a user ID between 1000 and 29999](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-users.html). So, assuming you haven't created any user with a lower UID, you could do:

```
awk -F: '$3>999 && $3<30000{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

And you could combine everything again (some services have regular user IDs but don't have a login shell, jira on my work server, for instance):

```
awk -F: '$3>999 && $3<30000 && $NF!~/\/false$/ && $NF!~/\/nologin$/ && $6~/\/home/{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just have one quick question, when using `awk -F: '$6~/\/home/{print $1}' /etc/passwd` I get the expected output except I get the users `syslog` and  ` cups-pk-helper` do you know what these users are?

Comment: @GreerPage they're the user used to run the syslog (system log) service and cups (printing) services, presumably. My bad, I tested this command on an Arch system, not Ubuntu, and arch doesn't give those home directories in `/home`. I added an approach combining the two original approaches which should filter those two users out. However, note that these are all _real_, _local_ users. I think you are assuming a functional difference between say `syslog` and your own user which simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry for the confusing question I don't know a lot of the vocabulary yet, but, thanks for the answer and helping me understand!

Comment: A better test would perhaps be UID. [UID 0-999](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-users.html) means system account on Debian and Ubuntu, while >1000 means normal user.

Comment: @GreerPage no reason to apologize! My first comments about local users wasn't telling you off, I was just trying to understand what you were after (you can have non-local users when using systems like LDAP for example). And again, my last comment here was just to let you know that you might be laboring under a misapprehension since there is no effective difference between your user and system users other than the ones I listed here, really.

Comment: @vidarlo that's completely user-configurable. I can happily create a user with a UID of 50 (`sudo adduser --uid 50 bob`). And there's no reason to assume that other services will always follow this convention either. But yes, that could also be used. I'll add something for that.

Comment: @terdon I'm totally aware that it's user configurable, and varies between different distros, but if the default convention is followed, it may provide some additional tool to discern between *user* accounts and *daemon* accounts.